# Can I ssh to a server through a pptp tunnel?

Tags: ssh, vpn, pptp

I'm new to VPNs, so there's a good chance I'm completely
misunderstanding my needs here.

My workplace is setup so that I can only ssh into its servers when
either (a) I'm using a computer in the building or (b) I'm connected via
VPN. Naturally, they only support VPN through Windows, so I'm on my own
for figuring out how to (and whether I even can) get it working on
linux.

I have a start on connecting to the VPN on the command line. If I type:

```
pon work
```

it'll connect using the settings in `/etc/ppp/peers/work` with the
following syslog output:

```
[pppd] pppd 2.4.6 started by root, uid 0
[pppd] Using interface ppp0
[pppd] Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/3
[pppd] pppd 2.4.6 started by root, uid 0
[pppd] Using interface ppp1
[pppd] Connect: ppp1 <--> /dev/pts/4
```

and then, 30 seconds later:

```
[pppd] LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests_
[pppd] Connection terminated.
[pppd] Modem hangup
[pppd] Exit.
[pppd] LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests_
[pppd] Connection terminated.
[pppd] Modem hangup
[pppd] Exit.
```

It's around here that I took a step back and realized that I have no
idea how I'll even know if it's working.

I did manage to find [this page on PPTP
routing](http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/routing.phtml), but I have no
idea what kind of route I even want to setup. Do I want client-to-LAN?

The server I'm connecting to is public-facing; it just only accepts ssh
connections from machines in the building (or, allegedly, over VPN). So
I don't see how client-to-LAN would help me, since I really just want
traffic to a particular IP address to go through the PPTP tunnel.

For all intents and purposes, my home machine has no GUI whatsoever. I'm
only interested in connecting to a single computer via port 22 through
the VPN.

My questions at this point:

1. Is what I'm trying to do possible (assuming I get my PPTP client
   working)?
2. Can you point me to any examples of somebody who's made this work?

All I can find are people doing the opposite (i.e. PPTP through an ssh
tunnel), and it doesn't help that I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Your question title is misleading. The question is about how to get your VPN running. That's not what you would expect from the title. Edit your question and make the title suitable.

Comment: That's not actually what I'm looking for. I'm sure I can figure out how to get the VPN client working, but I don't want to put any more time and energy into that unless I'm sure that my end goal is even possible.

Intuitively, this seems simple, but I can't find evidence that anyone else has done it.

Comment: @Maaatt You may be sure, ssh works trough ppp connection just fine, you may not worry about that. Also you do not need some tricky stuff to access your ssh server (assume it is available from vpn server, for vpn clients) after vpn is up.

Comment: VPN actually acts way below SSH - for any applications running over IP it is mostly transparent. Plus once the link is set up, a reasonable configured VPN will cause the client to set up the routes properly. Hence your problem really is getting the VPN running - http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-configure-ubuntu-fedora-linux-pptp-client.html might be of help.

Comment: The answer to your title question is: yes, trivially — it'll just work if you set up your VPN correctly. So your problem is really how to set up your VPN. We need to see your PPTP configuration (how you set up the link, and any relevant action triggered by bringing up the link).